# Prevent “Send error report to Microsoft”

Tags: java, windows

I'm working on java application which perform some Runtime sub-process on files, for some files I got error cause the Send error report to Microsoft window to appear ,I need to handle this error programmatically, without showing this window to user. Please can anyone help ?

Comment: Well, what is it in your code that is resulting in the runtime error? You don't want to suppress the dialog, that's just sweeping the rubbish under the carpet. Fix the error and the dialog will go away too.

Comment: im running .exe app over files through runtime process , and i see this error over some of them

Comment: This is not very clear. Is it your .exe that emits the error? If so why does it do so? What is the error? If you want help, be prepared to supply sufficient details.

Comment: no it is not my exe .,i install it from the web , and the error that exe could not read the file well , i can handle this situation for this file , but i dont want the user to see this error message

Comment: it is not my program the exe file

Answer (score 1):

To Suppress windows error reporting the .exe that is being invoked should not terminate with an unhandled exception. This only works if you have access to the source of the application.

Based on the [WER Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638%28v=vs.85%29) - you should use the Win32 API call [WerAddExcludedApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513617%28v=vs.85%29) to add the specific .exe files that you are intending to ignore to the per-user ignore list - you could create a simple stub-application that allows you to add applications by name to the ignore list. Then when you invoke the application it does not trigger the error.

Similarly you could create another application to remove them using the [WerRemoveExcludedApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513621%28v=vs.85%29).

Alternatives are to use JNI/JNA to make a class to encapsulate this functionality rather than using `Runtime.exec`

Here is a simple example using [Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/twall/jna), which is a simpler version of JNI (no C++ needed for the most part). Download the jna.jar and make it part of your project.

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class JNATest {

    public interface CLibrary extends StdCallLibrary {
        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("wer.dll", 
            CLibrary.class);
        int WerAddExcludedApplication(WString name, boolean global);
        int WerRemoveExcludedApplication(WString name, boolean global);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.WerAddExcludedApplication(new WString("C:\\foo.exe"), false);
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.WerRemoveExcludedApplication(new WString("C:\\foo.exe"), false);
    }
}
```

Basically, replace the new `WString(...)` value with the name of the application that you are intending to ignore. It should be ignored for the purposes of windows error reporting at that point.

Bear in mind that the `wer.dll` is only on Windows Vista and newer, so if this is a problem, then you may need to edit the registry entries manually.

Comment: WerAddExcludedApplication example are in c++,how can I use it in java?how can I add .exe file to the ignore list from cmd ?

Comment: You could either write a simple C++ application that does the job, or you could create a JNI class that contains the functionality; I'll update the answer with a small C/C++ example that will allow you Add/Remove applications from the reporting list

Comment: Can you please help me in JNI class ,I can handle java more than C/C++? thnx for help

Comment: thnx for help again , but does this mean that this code will not performed under windows XP ?

Comment: Whilst this is what @ama thinks she wants, it almost certainly isn't. Simply looking in the other direction when you app faults is not a good long term strategy. Do this and the app will simply close silently and the user won't even know that it has closed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I heartily concur, ignoring the exceptions is a really bad strategy. @ama - yes, the code as supplied will not work on Windows XP - the `wer.dll` library is not present on windows xp by default

Answer (score 0):

You can always use try-catch-finally statement:

```
try
{
    some code here (the code that is causing the error);
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    handle exception here;
}
```

It works for me...

**EDIT** Here is the link that can help you a little bit more:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/Java%20Language/TryCatch.html

Comment: i dont think this is the way... any java throwable shouldnt cause "Send error report"

Comment: I have tried to do that ,I put the execution code of process inside try-catch statement but I still see the window error

Comment: Then I suggest you take a look at this answer (even though it is for C#)... Since C# and Java are more alike than they are different: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java)
Anyway here is the answer for your question in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/a/473381/1178798